# Generate a ruby class in memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, metaprogramming

I have a requirement to convert an ActiveRecord model class into a MongoDB Document class automatically. I am able to do so using a rails generator which will read the attributes of a model and generate the new document.rb.

If a ActiveRecord model class looks like below:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :completed, :end_date, :name, :start_date
end
```

Then, a generated class confirming to Mongoid's structure will be as below:

```
class ProjectDocument
  field :name, type: String
  field :start_date, type: Date
  field :end_date, type: Date
  field :completed, type: Boolean
  field :created_at, type: Time
  field :updated_at, type: Time
end
```

But I don't want to store a different document files, one for each model. I want to be able to generate this document class on the fly, whenever the rails application is started.

Is this possible? Is this approach of generating and using classes from memory advised? I don't have constraints on changes to AR model structure; the document is flexible w.r.t data structure and changed columns will get added automatically.

Comment: its a bad idea to use :end as a accessor or field name

Comment: Oops, point taken. This is just sample code; not using it anywhere. Tweaked the question.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt would look something like this:

```
klass = Project
new_class = Object.const_set(klass.name + "Document", Class.new)
klass.columns.each do |c|
  new_class.class_eval do
    field c.name.to_sym, type: c.type
  end
end
```

You'll almost certainly have to do something more complicated to set the field type correctly, but this should give you a good starting point.